# Implement piping ("|") using C..(fork used)

Tags: c, gcc, pipe, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t childpid;
    pipe(fd);
    childpid=fork();
    if (childpid == -1)
    {
        perror("Error forking...");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid)   /*parent proces*/   //grep .c
    {
        wait(&childpid);        //waits till the child send output to pipe
        close(fd[1]);
        close(0);       //stdin closed
        dup2(fd[0],0);
        execlp(argv[2],argv[2],argv[3],NULL);

    }
    if (childpid==0)  //ls
    {
        close(fd[0]);   /*Closes read side of pipe*/
        close(1);       //STDOUT closed
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        execl(argv[1],NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i give command line argument as "ls grep .c" i should get all the ".c" files displayed.

Pseudocode:-
My child process will run "ls" & parent process will run "grep .c"..
Parent process waits till the child process completes so that child writes to the pipe.

Test run:-

```
bash-3.1$ ls | grep .c
1.c
hello.c
bash-3.1$ ./a.out ls grep .c
bash-3.1$
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Ok. I got the answer myself. I used "execl()" in the child process which doesnt search the filename using the $PATH environment variable....
If i change to execlp(), the program runs as expected.

Comment: You probably also don't want that "wait(&childpid);" (or its inaccurate comment) in there. It doesn't wait until data is coming from the child, it waits until the child process state changes - e.g. exit. If your child process writes more than a pipe's worth of data (maybe 8k) it will hang waiting for the parent to read, while the parent still waits for it to exit.

Comment: so, what should I actually do so that parent executes after the child has executed...?

Comment: read(2) from the parent end will block until there is data or EOF. The whole point of pipes is that both programs run concurrently.

Comment: For cleaner code do not use a triple if statement (it is not needed and adds extra calculations) you are either a failed fork, a child, or a parent so if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {...} else if(childpid == 0) {...} else{...}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple mistake: your `execl` call should actually be `execlp`. Besides, you can get rid of the `wait` and `close` statements. Then you should check the error code of `execlp`.

Comment: You don't need to test the return status of `exec*()` functions; if the function returns, it failed.  But you're correct that there should be some sort of error handling for a failed `exec*()` function.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, the `close(0)` and `close(1)` are unnecessary, the [dup2()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html) function automatically does that for you.

Comment: You're right.  The `close(0)` and `close(1)` would be relevant if the code used `dup()` rather than `dup2()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer answer in the question below for the code to implement pipe.

[Pipe implementation in Linux using c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166721/pipe-implementation-in-linux-using-c)