# Pipe implementation in Linux using c

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to implement following command,

`ls | grep "SOMETHING"`

in c programming language. Can anybody please help me with this.

I want to fork a child , where i will run ls command using execlp.
In the parent i get the output of the child and grep (once again using execlp).

Is it not possible?

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html

Comment: what help do you need? what did u try?

Comment: `system("ls | grep "SOMETHING"");` ?

Comment: can you be more specific

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the code for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
int pfds[2];
pipe(pfds);
if (!fork()) {
    close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
    dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
    close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
} else {
    close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
    dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
    close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
    execlp("grep", "SOMETHING", NULL);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The pipe is just read from one stdout and write to the other stdin.
Do you want to implement a shell interpreter with pipe feature?
First, you need a shell parser to parse the commond.
Then, you would have a pipe line feature.
...

Comment: No , i dont want to implement the shell interpreter. Using execlp , i want to execute ls and piped it to grep , which is also run using execlp.

Comment: why not run as a single command? That is a bit complicated. Though, **popen** is the best choice to get the output of shell command.